# What's the best way to seal a drafty door on an uneven transition without interfering with opening/closing?

Tags: doors, weatherstripping, draft, seal

I have a door that opens up over carpet. The rubber sweep that is already there makes it pretty difficult to open the door. What's the best way to seal this door?

[image: Test]

Comment: If that's an exterior door it should have a proper bottom-seal threshold, which would be raised above the level of the carpet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twin Draft Guards do a fantastic job, and simply remove the rubber sweep in place now.

[image: Twin Draft Guard]

Photo credit: [Amazon](http://a.co/aOCLF3l)

Otherwise, many of these sweeps are adjustable, and you can move them up slightly by loosening the screws and sliding them up slightly... Not sure if it will still seal at that brass trim though (can't tell from the picture).